# Mapping R ARIMA parameters to coefficient symbols

Tags: r, arima, mean, intercept

I'm trying to map the information R prints for an ARIMA model to the coefficients in the formulas that I'm familiar with. Here's what I have so far

- ar1 = $\varphi_1$, ar2 = $\varphi_2$, ...
- intercept = $c + \varepsilon_t$ **???**
- ma1 = $\theta_1$, ma2 = $\theta_2$, ...
- mean = $\mu + \varepsilon_t$ **??????**

where an AR(p) model is defined as

$X_t = c + \sum_{i=1}^p \varphi_i X_{t-i}+ \varepsilon_t$

and an MA(q) model is given by

$X_t = \mu + \varepsilon_t + \sum_{i=1}^q \theta_i \varepsilon_{t-i}$

Note: I have read [Definitions of coefficients from Arima {forecast}](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/124351/definitions-of-coefficients-from-arima-forecast), but it doesn't discuss the "intercept" and "mean" parameters.

Comment: See Issue 3 by [Stoffer](http://www.stat.pitt.edu/stoffer/tsa4/Rissues.htm).

Comment: @RichardHardy, if you want to convert that to an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I believe the question is a duplicate as these issues have been brought up a few times before. I will see if I can find the relevant thread(s). If not, I can probably write it up as you suggest.

Comment: What about [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/252718/convert-intercept-drift-term-to-constant-term-in-arima-auto-arima-functions)?

Comment: @RichardHardy Yes, mine is a duplicate of that question.

Comment: Let's mark it as such then.

Comment: Note one important aspect: [there are two prominent conventions for MA models, which differ in the signs of the coefficients](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/189847/1352), so don't be surprised if your MA coefficients have their signs flipped.